# How to trigger jenkins from gitlab without Jenkins CI?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

We are using GitLab community edition 12.7 and I want to configure GitLab to trigger Jenkins when there is a push/merge request to our repo.

Jenkins CI is not available on CE, I want to know how I can trigger Jenkins from GitLab?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try webhook. Install webhook plugin on jenkins and configure the url on gitlab for jenkins job.